# Insert/Update into Table with results of another query

Tags: mysql

In my application, I have two tables:  One for tracking records, and another where I'm tracking individual pageviews on certain pages.  Each page view event triggers a record to be written to my Views table.

In order to calculate stats, I've got a cron job where I'm trying to aggregate the count of these views, grouped by record_id and save them into a separate table.

If I run the following insert query, it works great.

```
insert into Details (record_id, views)
(select record_id, count(id) from Views where 1 group by record_id)
```

Unfortunately, this only works for Inserting, and I'm having a hard time coming up with a proper query to Insert/Update.  I've tried using `On Duplicate Key Update`, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it working with my existing query.  I'm hoping to avoid the alternative, wihch is scripting this in PHP and running a bunch of individual queries, if possible.

Here are my table definitions:

```
Views
id (int) PK
record_id (int)
created_at (date)

Details
record_id (int) PK
views (int)
```

**Note:** Also, in the future, I'm planning on adding more columns to the Details table to represent other statistics, so running a Truncate and re-running the original insert query above isn't really a viable solution.

Comment: how about deleting the record_id from the summary as step 1 - then rerun your insert?

Comment: Thats possible, however the plan is to add more columns in the Details table to represent other aggregate statistics... which is why i'm gunning for an insert, if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it to the end:

```
insert into Details (record_id, views)
(select record_id, count(id) from Views group by record_id)
on duplicate key update views = values(views);
```

For this to work, `record_id` must be unique, though.

Comment: that works perfectly.  My problem was with the "update views=values(views)" part of the query.  Thanks!